# Android Fragments with Tabs and Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

[image]

We are building an App as shown above that has nesting of Fragments.

1. Tabs Featuring - Details Tab and MAps Tab
2. Details Tab will have a slideshow - like the View Page Slider and information below that which will be scrollable.
3. Maps Tab which will display the maps.

[image]

I have implmented the tabs and maps as well as the Slider as seen above. Now i am confused how i can add content below the Slider which will make the Details Tab scrollable.

**What i have tried ?**

On CLicking the Details tab the Fragment will try to inflate two Fragment layouts inside it.

**AndroidTabLayoutActivity.java**

```
package com.mink7.abs;

import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import java.util.Random;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import com.viewpagerindicator.PageIndicator;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // FragmentTabHost tabHost;

                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                // tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabMode);

                TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

                /*
                 * mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                 *
                 * mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                 * mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                 *
                 * mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                 * mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
                 */

                // Tab for Photos
                TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Details");
                photospec.setIndicator("Details",
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
                Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
                photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

                // Tab for Songs
                TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maps");
                // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
                songspec.setIndicator("Maps",
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
                Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

                // Tab for Videos
                /*
                 * TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
                 * videospec.setIndicator("Videos",
                 * getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab)); Intent
                 * videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
                 * videospec.setContent(videosIntent);
                 */

                // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
                tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
                tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
                // tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
        }

}
```

**DetailsActivity.java**

```
package com.mink7.abs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;

public class DetailsActivity extends BaseSampleActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.place_details_layout);

        mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);


    }
}
```

**BaseSampleActivity.java**

```
package com.mink7.abs;

import java.util.Random;

import com.viewpagerindicator.PageIndicator;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public abstract class BaseSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;
    //FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.random:
                final int page = RANDOM.nextInt(mAdapter.getCount());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Changing to page " + page, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mPager.setCurrentItem(page);
                return true;

            case R.id.add_page:
                if (mAdapter.getCount() < 10) {
                    mAdapter.setCount(mAdapter.getCount() + 1);
                    mIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.remove_page:
                if (mAdapter.getCount() > 1) {
                    mAdapter.setCount(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                    mIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @HarshaMV! i am looking for the same sort of solution, can you share your blog link where you taught people to learn "how to get this" ? and please share your tutorial source link with me.. so i will try to make that one in my use - i have to create same kind of program - two tabs in one of them i have to use view page slider using images and below that i have to place text content.

Comment: @Sun i havent writen any blog for that. but it was pretty staright forward. i was using Sherlock Action bar. But Android has native Action bar. so it must be easier to get it working

Comment: can you share same kind of sample code with me ? my email id is: kimdsouza139@yahoo.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be aware Fragments nesting is supported since Android 4.2 or latest compatibility libraries. Previously it was simply not supported. As for content below - just put them it all in one more container

Comment: oh okay. Thanks a lot. You mean to say assign view pager to a container and below that i can add regular layout and add the content

Answer (score 3):

*I have successfully implemented a similar project using nested Fragments(4.2).

For the nested fragments, instead of using getSupportFragmentManager(), use getChildFragmentManager().

e.g. to use viewpagerFragment inside a tabFragment, sample code is :

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment 
{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                                      Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  ..
  ..
  ..
  mTabHost.setup(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),          
                                     getSupportFragmentManager(),R.layout.*);
  mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("label").setIndicator("tag"),
                    ViewPagerFragment.class, arg);
}

public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle         
                         savedInstanceState) 
{
    return inflater.inflate(.......);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


}
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return size;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
    {

    }

}*
```

Answer (score 3):

i did this using holoeverywhere, however should work similar with ABS, or "native"

```
public class FragmentTestTabs extends Fragment implements  ActionBar.TabListener, OnPageChangeListener {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         getSupportActivity().getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); 
         getSupportActivity().getSupportActionBar().addTab( getSupportActivity().getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText(getString(R.string.firtsRow))
                        .setTabListener(this));
         getSupportActivity().getSupportActionBar().addTab( getSupportActivity().getSupportActionBar().newTab().setText(getString(R.string.secondRow))
         .setTabListener(this));
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        getSupportActivity().getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs();
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentDiets());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentCurrentDiet());
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();

        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(mViewPager!=null)
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
         getSupportActivity().getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    }
```

and the fragment_view_pager its just a viewpager view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```