# How to create swipeable tab view in android 2.2 with different xml views & i want working buttons & imagebuttons on them

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-2.2-froyo

I am creating an android application on android version 2.2 froyo.I want to give 3 swipeable tabs on it which basically corresponds to 3 different xml views.Each xml view has 3 buttons and an imagebutton on it.I want all of them to work.
Please help me in solving this problem.
Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can achieve this by fragment tab manager with view-pager please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625048/android-fragments-with-tabs-and-viewpager) answer

Comment: the link which you have provided is for android 4.2,i am working on android 2.2

Comment: View pager is supported from api level 4 in support library. Please check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html